# What's the difference between the 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' and 'gnome' packages?

Tags: gnome, package-management

I wanted to install GNOME, but there appear to be two GNOME (meta)packages. One is called 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' and the other simply 'gnome'. I'm wondering what the difference between the two is.

As far as I can tell the latter is a Debian package. Could the 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' be a version of GNOME optimised for Ubuntu, as opposed to Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `gnome` is closer to the pure GNOME and the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is more Ubuntu specific.

- The package `gnome`

  Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components

  This is the GNOME Desktop environment, an intuitive and attractive
  desktop, with extra components.

  This meta-package depends on the standard distribution of the GNOME
  desktop environment, plus a complete range of plugins and other
  applications integrating with GNOME and Debian, providing the best
  possible environment to date.
- The package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

  The Ubuntu GNOME metapackage

  Ubuntu GNOME is an Ubuntu flavor that offers a mostly pure GNOME
  experience. This package depends on all of the core Ubuntu
  GNOME packages.

  It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that
  it not be removed.

Comment: So, if I understand things correctly, the 'gnome' package is optimised for Debian, and the 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' is optimised for Ubuntu?

Comment: right, updated my answer